# Dask dataframe read_csv error: Could not serialize object of type tuple

Tags: dask

Did not receive a resolution on the Dask Github page so asking here.

Github issue link: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5156

The issue:

Encountered the following error when reading this CSV (https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/data/allyears2k.csv):
**Code**:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.dataframe as dd
client = Client()
file = "allyears2k.csv"
df = dd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin-1', blocksize=None)
df.head()
```

**Error**:

TypeError: ('**Could not serialize object of type tuple**.', "(, (, (, , [.parser_f at 0x7f5e922f46a8>, (, , 0, None, b'\n'), b'Year,Month,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay,DepDelay,Origin,Dest,Distance,........

It works fine using the following Pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
datafile = "allyears2k.csv"
df=pd.read_csv(datafile, encoding='latin-1', dtype='object')
```

Following are the version details:

```
Python 3
Pandas 0.25.0
OS:
sh-4.2$ cat /etc/release
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"

dask and dask distributed: 
2.1.0
2.1.0
```

Adding screenshot of (the same) error even after specifying dtype=object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In pandas you required `dtype="object"`, but you didn't use this for Dask. On my system, with no dtype specified, I get a helpful message telling me a dtype I might specify to get different partitions to agree. If I use that, or indeed just "object", then it loads fine:

```
In [23]: df = dd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin-1', blocksize=None, dtype='object')
    ...: df.head()
Out[23]:
   Year Month DayofMonth DayOfWeek DepTime CRSDepTime ArrTime  ... CarrierDelay WeatherDelay NASDelay SecurityDelay LateAircraftDelay IsArrDelayed IsDepDelayed
0  1987    10         14         3     741        730     912  ...          NaN          NaN      NaN           NaN               NaN          YES          YES
1  1987    10         15         4     729        730     903  ...          NaN          NaN      NaN           NaN               NaN          YES           NO
2  1987    10         17         6     741        730     918  ...          NaN          NaN      NaN           NaN               NaN          YES          YES
3  1987    10         18         7     729        730     847  ...          NaN          NaN      NaN           NaN               NaN           NO           NO
4  1987    10         19         1     749        730     922  ...          NaN          NaN      NaN           NaN               NaN          YES          YES
```

Dask 2.1.0 (master)
Pandas 0.25.0
Python 3.7.3

Comment: I had tried dtype=object before. Didn't work. Added a screenshot. Not sure there's something wrong with my setup, version, or the environment. Will try experimenting in other environments and get back. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: as you can see, I am using the same versions as you. Does Dask perform any logging that I can share?

Comment: You may have output in the console you ran the notebook from, or the client has a method to get worker logs, which are also in the dashboard. Sometimes its better to start the scheduler and worker(s) in separate consoles, just so you can see the logs as they come.